# AddAtMostOne or-tools but add at most x instead of one

Tags: python, or-tools, resource-scheduling, cp-sat

I'm following https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling / https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/job_shop in python to help me with a task. [[image: Example problem]] I want to add a constraint similar to AddAtMostOne, but I don't want it to be at most 1, I want it to be at most another integer.

In the context of the Job Shop problem linked above, I want to have multiple's of the same machine. For example I want 2 Machine 1's. How would I add as a constraint use up to 2 Machine 1's simultaneously? I haven't added AddExactlyOne as in that tutorial for this reason.

Comment: Use Cumulative instead of NoOverlap.

Comment: I was looking at Cumulative but wasn't sure how to define demands. Capacity would be 2 Machine 1's in this example, for a specified interval, but what would the demand be? I'm assuming it must be <= capacity, but unsure how to define it.

Comment: I would suggest a demand of 1

Comment: Note: AtMostOne is a constraint on Boolean literals. Not really appropriate for jobshops

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try demand of 1. I was also considering using AddNoOverlap, but then I'd need to create ids for each sub-machine that is Machine 1. That might be easier as I will need to add no overlaps as well